# How to read a large file in blocks according to a custom rule in Java?

Tags: java

I have a large file I would like to read and process in blocks and not load it as a whole in the main memory.

I want to give my custom rule to determine how many rows it will read per block (If it is possible I would like a maximum value too).

For example, I have this file and I want every block to contain a single ID:

| ID | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fasdf | cdcsacd |
| 1 | d1d | ca2 |
| 1 | casca | 13123 |
| 1 | cascas | vdvvsd |
| 1 | zxccxv | qfewq |
| 2 | casc | 23asf |
| 2 | gtbt | v |
| 3 | zxczxc | asc |

In the first block I will read the first 5 lines of the file

In the second the next 2 lines

and in the last block I will only have the last line.

Let's say that the maximum lines of a single ID can be up to 10, and I will never need to read more than 10 lines of the file in one block.

Comment: Use a `BufferedReader` and `readLine()`. Then split that line based on whatever the delimiter is for columns and look at the ID. If the ID doesn't match the previous one, you have a new block.

Comment: Are you asking about a single read or just a grouping of multiple `nextLine`/`readLine` calls?

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't think that a single read will work. I want to do that "grouping" in order to load in the memory lines with a single ID per iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use BufferedReader instance to read large files in blocks. readLine() method can be used to read a single line of the file at a time.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LargeFileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int blockSize = 1000; // Number of lines to read per block
        int maxRows = 10000; // Maximum number of rows to read
        int rowCount = 0;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("large_file.txt"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && rowCount < maxRows) {
                // Process the line here
                System.out.println(line);
                rowCount++;
                if (rowCount % blockSize == 0) {
                    // Process the block of data here
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of blockSize=1000 I want the block size to be as big as the rows with the same ID. In my example above, I want the blockSize to be 5 lines in the first iteration, 2 lines in the second, and 1 line in the last one.

Comment: No problem because this code is reading line by line so u can add condition to do action when last id is != new id